# listview shows only one record twice

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview that displays records from and sql server view.
The data is filtered by customerid and has 2 unique records when the view is ran.
However the listview will only display the first record, and displays it twice.
So there are two records displayed in the listview, but it's not displaying the two records generated by the view, it is just displaying the 1st record in the view twice.
I hope this is clear.

What is going on?  I have been searching for hours with no luck.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstBeforeAfter"  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" InsertItemPosition="None">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="divreg">
            <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" cellpadding="2" class="tablebasic" style="vertical-align:top">
                <tr ID="Tr1" runat="server" align="center">
                    <td style="background-color:#7e0d7d; color:White; font-size:1.2em; font-weight:bold; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px">
                        Services
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </td>
    </LayoutTemplate>     

     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr style="">

             <td align="center">
                <div class="divwrap">
                <div class="left3ColHeader">
                   <b>Date</b>
               </div>
                <div class="mid3ColHeader">
                  <b>Stylist</b>
                </div>
               <div class="right3ColHeader">
                  <b>Services</b>
                </div> 
                    <div class="formclear">
                    </div>                     
                <div class="left3ColBorder">
                   <%# Eval("SchedStartDateTime", "{0:d}")%>
               </div>
                <div class="mid3ColBorder">
                  <%#Eval("FullName")%>
                </div>
               <div class="right3ColBorder">
                  <%#Eval("ServiceText")%>
                </div> 
                    <div class="formclear">
                    </div>

               <div class="left2ColHeader">
                    <b>Before Picture</b>
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColHeader">
                   <b>After Picture</b>
                </div>
                <div class="formclear">
                    </div>



               <div class="left2ColPicBorder">

               <asp:Image ID="imgLeft" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BeforePicPath") %>' runat="server" />
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColPicBorder">
                  <asp:Image  runat="server" ID="imgRight" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("AfterPicPath") %>' />
                </div>


                <div class="formclear">
                    </div>      

                <div class="left2ColBorder">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblBefore"  Width="95%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BeforePicName") %>'></asp:Label>
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColBorder">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAfter" Width="95%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AfterPicName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="formclear">
                    </div> 
                <div class="divreg">
                    <hr />
                </div>
                    <div class="formclear">
                    </div>       
              </div>
              </td>

         </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#ffffd9">

             <td align="center">
                <div class="divwrap">
                <div class="left3ColHeader">
                   <b>Date</b>
               </div>
                <div class="mid3ColHeader">
                  <b>Stylist</b>
                </div>
               <div class="right3ColHeader">
                  <b>Services</b>
                </div> 
                    <div class="formclear">
                    </div>                     
                <div class="left3ColBorder">
                   <%# Eval("SchedStartDateTime", "{0:d}")%>
               </div>
                <div class="mid3ColBorder">
                  <%#Eval("FullName")%>
                </div>
                <div class="right3ColBorder">
                <%# Eval("ServiceText").ToString%>
                </div>

                    <div class="formclear">
                    </div>

               <div class="left2ColHeader">
                    <b>Before Picture</b>
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColHeader">
                   <b>After Picture</b>
                </div>
                <div class="formclear">
                    </div>

               <div class="left2ColPicBorder">

               <asp:Image ID="imgLeft" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BeforePicPath") %>' runat="server" />
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColPicBorder">
                  <asp:Image  runat="server" ID="imgRight" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("AfterPicPath") %>' />
                </div>


                <div class="formclear">
                    </div>      

                <div class="left2ColBorder">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblBefore"  Width="95%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BeforePicName") %>'></asp:Label>
               </div>
                <div class="right2ColBorder">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAfter" Width="95%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AfterPicName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="formclear">
                    </div> 
                <div class="divreg">
                    <hr />
                </div>
                    <div class="formclear">   </div>       
              </div>
              </td>             
         </tr>         
     </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

 Protected Sub LoadPortfolio(ByVal iCustID As Integer)
    Dim dc As New SalonDataClassesDataContext


    Dim q = From p In dc.vClientStyles Where p.CustomerID = iCustID Order By p.SchedStartDateTime Descending Select p
    If q.Count > 0 Then
        Me.lstBeforeAfter.DataSource = q
        Me.lstBeforeAfter.DataBind()

    End If


End Sub

SELECT ISNULL(dbo.Services.ServiceID, 0) AS ServiceID, dbo.Schedules.SchedStartDateTime, dbo.Schedules.ServiceText, dbo.Schedules.CustomerID, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.Services.Completed, 0) AS Completed, dbo.Stylists.FullName, dbo.Stylists.StylistID, ISNULL(dbo.Services.BeforePicName, 'No Title') AS BeforePicName, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.Services.BeforePicPath, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg') AS BeforePicPath, ISNULL(dbo.Services.AfterPicName, 'No Title') AS AfterPicName, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.Services.AfterPicPath, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg') AS AfterPicPath
FROM  dbo.Schedules INNER JOIN dbo.Stylists ON dbo.Schedules.UserID = dbo.Stylists.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Services ON dbo.Schedules.ServiceID = dbo.Services.ServiceID
ORDER BY dbo.Schedules.SchedStartDateTime DESC
```

Changed to union query but linq does not like it.

```
SELECT ISNULL(dbo.Schedules.ServiceID, 0) AS ServiceID,     dbo.Schedules.SchedStartDateTime, dbo.Schedules.ServiceText, dbo.Schedules.CustomerID, 
ISNULL(dbo.Schedules.Completed, 0) AS Completed, dbo.Stylists.FullName,      dbo.Stylists.StylistID, 'No Title' AS BeforePicName, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg' AS     BeforePicPath, 'No Title' AS AfterPicName, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg' AS AfterPicPath
FROM dbo.Schedules INNER JOIN  dbo.Stylists ON dbo.Schedules.UserID = dbo.Stylists.UserID
Where dbo.Schedules.CustomerID = 27
UNION 
SELECT ISNULL(dbo.Services.ServiceID, 0) AS ServiceID,            dbo.Schedules.SchedStartDateTime, dbo.Schedules.ServiceText, dbo.Schedules.CustomerID, 
ISNULL(dbo.Services.Completed, 0) AS Completed, dbo.Stylists.FullName,     dbo.Stylists.StylistID, ISNULL(dbo.Services.BeforePicName, 'No Title') AS BeforePicName, 
ISNULL(dbo.Services.BeforePicPath, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg')  AS BeforePicPath, ISNULL(dbo.Services.AfterPicName, 'No Title') AS AfterPicName,      ISNULL(dbo.Services.AfterPicPath, '../images2020/resume-photo.jpg') AS AfterPicPath
FROM dbo.Schedules INNER JOIN dbo.Stylists ON dbo.Schedules.UserID = dbo.Stylists.UserID INNER JOIN dbo.Services ON dbo.Schedules.ServiceID = dbo.Services.ServiceID
Where dbo.Schedules.CustomerID = 27 ORDER BY dbo.Schedules.SchedStartDateTime DESC
```

I now get the error... The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3

The data returned in the DataKeyNames must be unique. The fact that you have the same CustomerID means that you need another column to make a unique key. In theory you could have CustomerID and ServiceID in the DataKeyNames but the fact that you have some null ServiceID records makes it difficult.

Why not add a new column to each select called "MyUniqueID" and set its value to NewId(). Then use MyUniqueID as the DataKeyNames.

```
 SELECT NewId() as MyUniqueID from blah
```

The NewId() function will ensure that you get a globally unqiue identifier for each row in your result set but do not use UniqueID for any subsequent operations because the data is not persisted in the database so will be lost each time the ListView is refreshed.

It's difficult to see why you are using a union in your example mainly due to the fact it is difficult to format the stackoverflow code block. However it is clear you have the same customer ID more than once so it can not be used as a unique DataKeyName on its own.

Or maybe `CustomerID + UserID` in the `Schedules` is unique and should be combined in the DataKeyNames??

Specify multiple columns in the DataKeyNames as follows:-

```
DataKeysNames="CustomerID,UserID,ServiceID"
```

If this doesn't work you should explain what you expect to be returned to your `ListView` for a single `CustomerID` and what unique properties each record in the `ListView` will have

*Take out the union, your first example seemed to work the best except for uniqueness*

Comment: No they have the same ID.  I am doing a select statement where customerid = customerid

Comment: Ok, I will also add the view to the original question

Comment: Yes, sometimes the serviceid is null, which I convert to 0 if null. The only filter is the customerid.  What I'm doing is listing all the schedules and if exists services.

Comment: Changed view to stored procedure and instead of left outer join did union.  Now get error... The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.